# Find multiple max values from a table of different accounts at a same time in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let suppose we have a data dump of customer details `(account, invoiceAmount, invoiceDate).`
This record contains multiple invoiceDates data. I have to fetch the record of such customers having last three invoiceDates. `[MAX(invoiceDate), MAX(invoiceDate)-1, MAX(invoiceDate)-2]`

Every customers might have different invoices.

```
account         invoicedate ageamount
1-129285408641  2016-02-08  92
1-129285650772  2016-02-08  666
1-129285408641  2016-07-08  717
1-129285650772  2016-07-08  885
1-129285650772  2015-09-08  766
1-129285408641  2016-05-08  1479
1-129285650772  2016-05-08  637
1-129285650772  2015-10-08  682
1-129285408641  2016-03-08  668
1-129285650772  2016-01-08  637
1-129285650772  2015-08-08  439
1-129285650772  2015-12-08  641
1-129285650772  2015-07-08  109
1-129285408641  2016-06-08  183
1-129285650772  2016-06-08  914
1-129285650772  2016-08-08  415
1-129285408641  2016-08-08  1198
1-129285650772  2016-10-08  579
1-129285408641  2016-11-08  250
1-129285650772  2016-11-08  1148
1-129285650772  2015-11-08  694
1-129285408641  2015-09-08  1363
1-129285650772  2016-03-08  748
1-129285408641  2016-01-08  1347
1-129285408641  2015-11-08  442
1-129285408641  2015-08-08  409
1-129285408641  2015-12-08  918
1-129285408641  2015-07-08  109
1-129285408641  2016-04-08  421
1-129285650772  2016-04-08  637
1-129285650772  2016-09-08  1000
1-129285408641  2016-09-08  119
1-129285408641  2016-10-08  1228
```

Sample data, i have to fetch the last there invoices of theses 2 sample accounts.

Whats the query?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide more details

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result

Comment: @Mansoor how do i share sample data?

Comment: @viki888 Question is now edited.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir do you want to display all the last three invoices in a single row?

Comment: Yes it might be in a single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not actually specified whether you want this in the same or different rows, here are both solutions:

```
-- Build up the test data:
declare @t table(account nvarchar(50), invoicedate date, ageamount int);
insert into @t values
,('1-129285408641','2016-01-08',1347)
,('1-129285408641','2015-11-08',442 )
,('1-129285408641','2015-08-08',409 )
,('1-129285408641','2015-12-08',918 )
,('1-129285408641','2015-07-08',109 )
,('1-129285408641','2016-04-08',421 )
,('1-129285650772','2016-04-08',637 )
,('1-129285650772','2016-09-08',1000)
,('1-129285408641','2016-09-08',119 )
,('1-129285408641','2016-10-08',1228);


-- To return last three invoice dates in the same row:
with cte
as
(
    select account
            ,invoicedate
            ,row_number() over (partition by account order by invoicedate desc) as rownum
    from @t e
)
select Account
        ,[1] as MostRecentInvoiceDate
        ,[2] as SecondMostRecentInvoiceDate
        ,[3] as ThirdMostRecentInvoiceDate
from 
( 
    select c.account
            ,c.invoicedate
            ,c.rownum
    from cte c 
        join @t t on c.account = t.account
    where c.rownum <= 3
)a
pivot
    (
    max(invoicedate) for rownum in ([1],[2],[3])
    ) pvt1;


-- To return last three invoice dates as seperate rows:
with cte
as
(
    select account
            ,invoicedate
            ,row_number() over (partition by account order by invoicedate desc) as rownum
    from @t e
)
select Account
        ,InvoiceDate
        ,rownum
from cte
where rownum <= 3
order by account
        ,invoicedate desc;
```

Comment: Excellent, but dear here I want the invoicedate as well.